# How to retouch video on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-editor

I need to cover up some areas like they wasn't there.
Is there such application (budget preferably) or should I combine several applications ? I'm do not consider expensive stuff like soft from Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use blender. Not because it is especially suiting for this case, but because it is open-source and versatile.

You can find it in your ubuntu software store.

What you need to know about blender: It has a very steep learning curve, but once you understand it, you can do pretty much anything with it. From image editing over creating games to making renderings undistinguishable from real life footage.

For "covering up": Use the sequence editor and combine your footage via Alpha filters and whatever you wanna cover it up with(3D-model or video snippet). You may wanna use Motion tracking, which is integrated. Can't get more specific than that without having more information...

Comment: Thanks. Would be cool if you would describe it in more details here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111969/how-should-i-retouch-videos-repaint-areas